# Random Generator using UNIFORM

Tags: vhdl, uniform

I am trying to generate a random number for a little game and I tried to use the UNIFORM function from the package MATH_REAL.

I get a value when I test my code, but it never changes. I tried to make the code happen at every rising_edge but it didn't change anything. I couldn't find or think of an effective fix.

I think I know that problem is simply that my random number is generated only once, but I couldn't figure out a way to change this.

Here is what I implemented (my variation with the clock) :

```
    rand: process (count1) 
        variable seed1, seed2 : positive;
        variable rand : real;
        variable int_rand : integer range 1 to 5;
    begin
        if rst_i='1' then
            count1 <= 1;
        elsif rising_edge(clk_i) then
            UNIFORM(seed1, seed2, rand);
            int_rand := INTEGER(TRUNC(rand*5.0));
            count1 <= int_rand;
        end if;
    end process;
```

The value of count1 is then used in another process. The above code gives the same simulation results as simply :

```
    rand: process (count1) 
        variable seed1, seed2 : positive;
        variable rand : real;
        variable int_rand : integer range 1 to 5;
    begin
        UNIFORM(seed1, seed2, rand);
        int_rand := INTEGER(TRUNC(rand*5.0));
        count1 <= int_rand;
    end process;
```

Is there a simple way to ensure more that a random number is generated more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the purpose is to generate a random number on `count1` for every rising edge of `clk_i`, then update the sensitivity list for the process to (assuming async reset by `rst_i`):

```
rand: process (rst_i, clk_i)
```

This will make the process reexecute at every change of `rst_i` or `clk_i`, where the sensitivity list of `count1` reexecutes at change of `count1` only.

Note that `variable int_rand : integer range 1 to 5;` should be `range 0 to 4`, since uniform result is > 0.0 and < 1.0.

An interesting behavior is, that a sensitivity list of `rand: process (count1)` as for the second process, without the `if` guarding generation on `count1`, will actually make the process reexecute several times start of simulation, until the generated `count1` value is identical to the previous `count1` value, in which case the is no change on `count1` to trigger reexecution of the process, and then process is then not executed any more.

Comment: Thank you for both indicating me the error in the sensitivity list and the range of the integer. It works just fine now.
It is indeed interesting, the way my process behaved before, thank you for the explanation. I can look back on how I implemented it and tell to me "what a fool".

Comment: I get often the min and max value (0 and 4 here, as it is the range of my integer). I can't explain why, either that the `rand` variable gives often a value near of 0.0 or 1.0. Is this true? Of course, pseudo-random isn't random, but still, it amazes me how often I get these min and max values in my simulations. Maybe do you know why?

Comment: In a run I got for 0 .. 4: 20145, 19995, 20001, 19888, 19959, so that looks like a pretty nice even distribution.  Try to do a long run and count the number of occurrences of 0 to 4 if you want to see if there is an odd distribution; there shouldn't be for long runs.

Comment: I did what you said, my runs weren't long enough! Thank's